# Different results from printing cursor.fetchall()

Tags: python, cursor, mysql-python, fetchall

I have a cursor on database `db` like :

```
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "user", "pass")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
print(cursor.fetchall())
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
```

Why first output is an empty tuple `()` while the second output lists my records correctly like : `((A,C),(B,D))` ?